# MATLAB Solution curves not fitting slope field using quiver and dsolve

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, graphing

Given a first order differential equation...

dy/dx = 0.01y(1 - y)(y - 1/2)

I am trying to create a slope field and show some specific solution curves but for some reason the curves do not appear to fit the vectors perfectly.

Here is the output:
[image: solution curves]
If you look at the two middle curves their slope does not appear to follow the vectors. Is this an artifact of the plot itself or have I done something wrong?

I spent some time getting the slope field to show up well and perhaps the reason the solution curves don't fit is because of the spacing between points, but I am not sure.

Here is the code:

```
    [T Y] = meshgrid(-200:10:200, -2:0.1:2);
    dY = 0.01.*Y.*(1-Y).*(Y-(0.5));
    dT = ones(size(dY));
    L = sqrt(dT.^2 + dY.^2);
    figure
    quiver(T, Y, dT./(L), dY./L, .6, 'AutoScale', 'off',                         'ShowArrowHead', 'off');
    axis tight
    hold on
    grid on
    axis([-200 200 -2 2])

    syms x y
    de = 'Dy = 0.01*y*(1-y)*(y-(0.5))';

    y1 = dsolve(de, 'y(0) = -1', 'x');
    y1 = expand(y1);

    y2 = dsolve(de, 'y(0) = 1/4', 'x');
    y2 = expand(y2);

    y3 = dsolve(de, 'y(0) = 3/4', 'x');
    y3 = expand(y3);

    y4 = dsolve(de, 'y(0) = 2', 'x');
    y4 = expand(y4);

    for fxn = [y1 y2 y3 y4]
        fplot(fxn, [-200 200], 'LineWidth', 2)
        hold on
    end
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like an artifact of the plot. The slope in the middle makes for less than 1 pixel in height difference in the segments, the solution curves also have that slope of 10-20 pixel per 20 segments. You can see some of the correct slope in the smudges of the anti-aliasing. If you were to produce the picture in a higher resolution, you should see better that the slope segments are not really horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

`Quiver` is plotted with well defined origin points on a rectangular grid (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html). Instead of say tons of curves with unevenly dashed plots where dashes would match value at that point.

At the center, lines are nearly horizontal. Therefore, it will seem as if your low slope of purple and orange curves intersects quivers and does not follow the supposed lines.
If you zoom in near the curves, you will see the difference and that both curves in fact correctly follow the slope.

Unfortunately, you are unable to fix this issue by denser mesh grid with quiver. Suppose you add 10x the points to `T` and `Y` - all the graph will be an ocean of blue, yet zooming near the purple line will still show this same problem.

Now, what you can do is a manual "quiver-like" plot in the central region, say from 0 to 1 on Y. Select starting Y, and X points, perhaps the same as yours now. Draw first lines corresponding to the same quivers. Now, instead of keeping subsequent Y points the same for other vectors, calculate where they would have to be if the line would continue - `Ynext = Y+dY*(T(i)-T(i-1))`. Calculate the same dY, dT and L for that modified Y point for the next round of points and repeat until you reach end of bounds.

Say this code (I would still have to fix lengths and correct offsets, but the general idea would be like following):

```
Ycentral = 0:0.1:1;
Ynext = Ycentral;
numX = length(x);
for i = 1 : numX   
    [T2, Y2] = meshgrid(x(i), Ynext);
    dY = 0.01 * Ynext .* (1-Ynext).*(Ynext - 0.5);
    dT = ones(size(dY));
    L = sqrt(dT.^2 + dY.^2);    

    quiver(T2', Y2', dT./(L), dY./L, .6, 'AutoScale', 'off', 'ShowArrowHead', 'off');

    Ynext = Ynext + dY;
end
```